# This easy python code suddenly doesn't work

Tags: python

I created a little program as part of my learning experience using python crash course and the code worked pretty well yesterday. But now that I woke up and tried to launch the thing it refuses to do anything and says that "self" is not defined. I honestly have no idea why it happens and would very much like to know exactly what causes error and where I mistaken. Sorry if the question format is wrong and thanks in advance for any help.

```py
import json

class Save_user:
    """Greet the user if the username presents."""
    """Ask the name otherwise."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Sets username; Calls greet_user()"""
        self.file_path = 'username.json'
        self.greet_user()

    def get_stored_username(self):
        """Get the username if stored."""
        try:
            with open(self.file_path) as f:
                self.username = json.load(f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return None
        else:
            return self.username

    def greet_user(self):
        """Choose greet the user or store the username."""
        self.get_stored_username()
        if self.username:
            self.if_same_user()
        else:
            self.store_name()

    def store_name(self):
        """Store username."""
        self.username = input("Enter your username: ")
        with open(self.file_path, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(self.username, f)
        print("Great! We'll greet you next time!")

    def if_same_user(self):
        """Check if the same user."""
        print(f"Are you {self.username}?")
        while True:
            response = input("Please, Enter 'yes' or 'no': \n")
            response = response.lower().strip()
            if response == 'yes' or response == 'y':
                print(f"Welcome back, {self.username}!")
                break
            elif response == 'no' or response == 'n':
                self.store_name()
                break

useame = Save_user()
```

The program should asks the user's name if the `json` file exists and create the file and store the name otherwise. I tried to set username to 0 in `__init__` module and I could launch the thing with text editor and .py format, visual studio, however is giving me an error. Again, thanks in advance for any help!

UPD TraceBack:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\python_work\New folder\new.py", line 50, in <module>  
    username = Save_user()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\python_work\New folder\new.py", line 10, in __init__  
    self.greet_user()
  File "c:\Users\Windows 10\Desktop\python_work\New folder\new.py", line 25, in greet_user
    if self.username:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Save_user' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work just fine. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Thanks. Provided the traceback. So I should reinstall my python?

Comment: @Max_CSDLoradon your python is fine. Your issue is understanding how to define properties in a class and how it works. There are several ways to fix your issue. You'll learn those keep practicing :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises when the file is not found: you return None, but don't actually asign it to `self.username`. So when you do `if self.username`, an error will rise. I tweaked two lines of your code, here are the functions to change:

```py
    def get_stored_username(self):
        """Get the username if stored."""
        try:
            with open(self.file_path) as f:
                username = json.load(f)
                return username
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return None


    def greet_user(self):
        """Choose greet the user or store the username."""
        self.username = self.get_stored_username()
        if self.username:
            self.if_same_user()
        else:
            self.store_name()
```

Comment: Thanks. At least it started and let me enter my name. On the second start, however when it promted me if i was the same user after entering yes it called NameError: name 'username' is not defined. And the weirdest thing is that yesterday it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The traceback is very helpful here. The problem is that `__init__` calls `self.greet_user()`, which expects `self.username` to exist. But `self.username` does not exist yet.

```py
class Save_user:
    def __init__(self):
        """Sets username; Calls greet_user()"""
        self.file_path = 'username.json'
        self.greet_user()
        # NOTE: there is no self.username here

    # ...

    def greet_user(self):
        """Choose greet the user or store the username."""
        self.get_stored_username() # May fail to set self.username
        if self.username: # This will cause an error
            self.if_same_user()
        else:
            self.store_name()
```

Typically, attempting to instantiate an object of this class when there is no file `username.json` will cause an `AttributeError` that `self.username` is not one of the attributes. One way to solve this would be to add a sentinel or default username, such as

```py
    # ...
    def __init__(self):
        self.file_path = 'username.json'
        self.username = 'default'
        self.greet_user()
    # ...
```

A different default name (especially one that is not allowed to be set by standard means) would be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks. But the programm still crashes when it promts if the same user with "name 'username' is not defined" even if I declare self.username in that same method

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the method `get_stored_username`

you are returning `None` instead of defining the property `self.username`

```py
    def get_stored_username(self):
        """Get the username if stored."""
        try:
            with open(self.file_path) as f:
                self.username = json.load(f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return None # <- error
        else: # <- not necessary
            return self.username  # <- not necessary
```

Define the property:

```py
    ...
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.username = None
```

complete method:

```py
    def get_stored_username(self):
        """Get the username if stored."""
        try:
            with open(self.file_path) as f:
                self.username = json.load(f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.username = None
```

Comment: Thanks. But even with the fix implemented it still says:
"NameError: name 'username' is not defined"

And some people here mentioned the code worked just fine for them it's just weird.

Comment: Made an edit with how it should look like. It is working for me.